# localtime_r supposed to be thread safe, but causing errors in Valgrind DRD

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind, localtime

I searched google as much as I could but I couldn't find any good answers to this.

localtime_r is supposed to be a thread-safe function for getting the system time. However, when checking my application with Valgrind --tool=drd, it consistantly tells me that there is a data race condition on this function. Are the common search results lying to me, or am I just missing something? It doesn't seem efficient to surround each localtime_r call with a mutex, especially if it is supposed to by thread safe in the first place. here is how i'm using it:

```
timeval handlerTime;
gettimeofday(&handlerTime,NULL);

tm handlerTm;
localtime_r(&handlerTime.tv_sec,&handlerTm);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [documentation](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/localtime_r.3.asp) says it is *reentrant* (and thus *thread-safe*), then it is.

If ever there was a bug in the code (not your code) and the function wasn't really *thread-safe*, there is nothing much you can do about it (unless using another function), and it's not up to you to *fix* this in your code: the function **must** behave the way it is documented.

However, I would be careful with the results given by `valgrind`. It is a great tool, and I use it often. But sometimes, it is just *wrong*. And for something as hard as detecting race conditions, I would be even more careful about what it says. Especially about a standard function that is beeing used for decades.

My advice here would be: just ignore it. If you ever experience issues and believe `localtime_r()` is responsible for it, write to the appropriate mailing-list to report the issue, and/or use another function.

In the meanwhile, you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage:

> The ctime_r(), localtime_r(), and
>   tzset() functions are MT-Safe in 
>   multithread  applications,  as  long 
>   as no user-defined function directly
>   modifies one of the following
>   variables: timezone, altzone,
>   daylight, and  tzname.  These four 
>   variables are not MT-Safe to access.
>   They are modified by the tzset()
>   function in an MT-Safe manner.  The
>   mktime(), localtime_r(), and ctime_r()
>   functions call tzset().

As long as you aren't accessing any of those variable directly in your code, it seems possible that valgrind is reporting a false positive. Does it give you any further detail about where it thinks the race condition exists within the function?

Unless you have further corroboration with valgrind, I would think it's safe to continue using it without extra locks.

Comment: [localtime_r() does not call tzset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170721/real-time-awareness-of-timezone-change-in-localtime-vs-localtime-r)