# Real-time awareness of timezone change in localtime() vs localtime_r()

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, time, localtime

Working on an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS box, I just noticed that localtime() and localtime_r() behave differently when the system's timezone changes during the lifetime of a process: localtime() picks up the timezone change immediately, whereas localtime_r() does not, it seems to stick to what was the timezone at the launch of the process. Is this expected behavior? I haven't seen this covered anywhere.

More precisely, when I use the following code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    printf("localtime:%02d/%02d/%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_year + 1900,
           tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

... and change the timezone from UTC via ...

```
# echo 'Europe/Berlin' > /etc/timezone 
# sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

... then the code produces the following, ...

```
localtime:10/04/2013-01:11:33
localtime:10/04/2013-01:11:34
localtime:10/04/2013-01:11:35
localtime:10/03/2013-23:11:36
localtime:10/03/2013-23:11:37
localtime:10/03/2013-23:11:38
```

... but if I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm local_tm;
    struct tm *tm = localtime_r(&t, &local_tm);    
    printf("localtime_r:%02d/%02d/%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_year + 1900,
           tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

... then there's no change when doing a similar timezone change:

```
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:37
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:38
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:39
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:40
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:41
localtime_r:10/04/2013-01:15:42
```

UPDATE: adding a call to tzset() before invoking localtime_r() produces the expected behavior. Whether that's clear from the spec/manpage or not (see discussion below) is a question for mentalhealth.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this following documentation:

> The localtime() function converts the calendar time timep to
>   broken-down time representation, expressed relative to the user's
>   specified timezone. The function acts as if it called tzset(3) and
>   sets the external variables tzname with information about the current
>   timezone, timezone with the difference between Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) and local standard time in seconds, and daylight to a
>   nonzero value if daylight savings time rules apply during some part of
>   the year. The return value points to a statically allocated struct
>   which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and
>   time functions. The localtime_r() function does the same, but stores
>   the data in a user-supplied struct. It need not set tzname, timezone,
>   and daylight.

From: http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r

So as far as I can tell, it appears that the code is working as I'd expect.

Edited to add more from the same documentation:

> According to POSIX.1-2004, localtime() is required to behave as though
>   tzset(3) was called, while localtime_r() does not have this
>   requirement. For portable code tzset(3) should be called before
>   localtime_r().

Comment: Thanks Pete, I saw that. To me the sentence "It does not set tzname, timezone, and daylight" conveys something very different -- these are external values. My code uses none of these, and my question is about the return value of localtime()/localtime_r(), and the snippet you post says "does the same".

Comment: "The function acts as if it called tzset(3)" in localtime(), not localtime_r().  The timezone is never set when you call localtime_r().  So basically, as the documentation is showing, localtime_r() never sets the timezone, and therefore you will always get UTC time.  Try calling tzset() prior to localtime_r and they should behave the exact same way.

Comment: I see your point -- but then shouldn't the text say something about the extent to which these two functions *rely* on the value of the tzname/timezone/daylight globals, not about the extent to which they *set* it? I find this really confusing, because *my* code doesn't care in any way about the values of these globals.

Comment: Also, for the record, the spec is correct -- adding tzset() produces consistent behavior.

Comment: Yea, Linux man pages are cyptic.  I find that a strong ale prior to attempting to read them helps.  Cheers!

Comment: *lol* -- less coffee and more beer sounds just about perfect now... Cheers!