# Linux/crossplatform API for timezone rules? (replace locking localtime_r)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, timezone

We have some code that wants to call `localtime` very often from multiple threads. (Relevant background: it's a server where one of the things you can ask it for is the local time as a string, and it wants to be able to serve 100Ks of requests per second.)

We have discovered that on Ubuntu Linux 12.04, the glibc function `localtime_r` ("reentrant localtime") calls `__tz_convert`, which [still takes a global lock!](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/time/tzset.c.html)

(Also, it looks like [FreeBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/localtime.c?rev=1.78) makes `localtime_r` call `tzset` on every single invocation, because they're paranoid that the program might have done a `setenv("TZ")` and/or the user downloaded a new version of `/etc/localtime` between now and the last time `localtime_r` was called. (This is the opposite of the situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170721/real-time-awareness-of-timezone-change-in-localtime-vs-localtime-r); it seems that glibc calls `tzset` [on every invocation of `localtime` but not `localtime_r`](http://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=154), just to be confusing.)

Obviously, this is terrible for performance. For our purposes, we would like to basically "snapshot" the rules for our current timezone when the server starts running, and then use that snapshot forever afterward. So we'd continue to respect Daylight Savings Time rules (because the rules for when to switch to DST would be part of the snapshot), but we would never go back to the disk, take mutexes, or do anything else that would cause threads to block. (We are fine with not respecting downloaded updates to tzinfo and not respecting changes to `/etc/localtime`; we don't expect the server to physically change timezones while it's running.)

However, I can't find any information online about how to deal with timezone rules — whether there's a userspace API for working with them, or whether we'll be forced to reimplement a few hundred lines of glibc code to read the timezone data ourselves.

Do we have to reimplement everything downstream of `__tz_convert` — including `tzfile_read`, since it doesn't seem to be exposed to users? Or is there some POSIX interface and/or third-party library that we could use for working with timezone rules?

(I've seen http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html but I'm not sure it's helpful.)

Comment: It is not at all obvious that the global lock in `tzset` is "terrible for performance" — did you actually benchmark it? Unless you benchamrked it, it appears to be a case of the proverbial premature optimization. As far as I can tell, `tzset` has a fast path that basically does nothing if the time zone hasn't actually changed. In a real-life application I would expect the lock to never be contended.

Comment: The lock is contended any time two threads call `__tz_convert` at once; check the code. And yes, the only reason we know this lock exists is that we saw it being a bottleneck in perf tests (specific tests that served a lot of localtime requests).

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html) or [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime)?

Comment: It looks like [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html) can do what we want, but it looks pretty heavyweight in terms of dependencies. (We're not currently a "Boost shop".) However, if there's no easier solution... Boost is definitely a possibility.

Comment: I'm not much of a C++ guru, but I know that both Boost and ICU have IANA TZDB implementations.  I also know that ICU is being used by [the v8-i18n project](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/) and several others, so it *might* be lighter weight than Boost, but I'm not really sure.  Perhaps someone else more familiar can offer a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/google/cctz

It's fast and should do everything you want with a very simple API.

In particular, for a cctz equivalent to `localtime`, use the `cctz::BreakTime()` function. For example, https://github.com/google/cctz/blob/master/examples/example3.cc

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: Thank you Greg. That library looks great. There is a global lock in your library too, see https://github.com/google/cctz/blob/master/src/time_zone_impl.cc#L64 . Found by Cloudera as descirbed in comments at https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-3316 . Submitted https://github.com/google/cctz/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [free, open-source timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) would fit the need.

It has a configuration flag called `LAZY_INIT` which is fully documented [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  By default it is on, and will cause calls to `std::call_once` the first time each individual timezone is accessed.  However you can compile with:

```
-DLAZY_INIT=0
```

and then the calls to `std::call_once` go away.  Every single timezone is read from disk and fully initialized on first access (via a function local static).  From then on, things are stable and lock-free, with no disk access.  Naturally this increases initialization time up front, but decreases the "first-access" time for each timezone.

This library requires C++11/14, and so may not be suitable for that reason.  It is based on (and heavily uses) the C++11 `<chrono>` library.  Here is sample code that prints out the current local time:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    auto local = make_zoned(current_zone(), std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout << local << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2016-04-12 10:13:14.585945 EDT
```

The library is a modern, high-performance thread safe design.  It is also very flexible and fully documented.  Its capabilities go far beyond a simple replacement for C's `localtime`.  Unlike the C API, you can specify any [IANA timezone](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) you need, for example:

```
    auto local = make_zoned("Europe/London", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

This gives the current time in London:

```
2016-04-12 15:19:59.035533 BST
```

Note that by default the precision of the timestamp is that of `std::chrono::system_clock`.  If you prefer another precision, that is easily accomplished:

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
auto local = make_zoned("Europe/London", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << format("%F %H:%M %Z", local) << '\n';

2016-04-12 15:22 BST
```

See the [docs](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) for more details.